# ember call controller from template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i'm working with Emberjs and I still have trouble to fully get how to bound controller from templates.

I have one model: date_model.js

```
WebCalendar.Dates = DS.Model.extend({
    today: DS.attr('date'),
    monthNumber: function(){
        var today =  this.get('today');
        return today.getMonth();
    }.property('today'),
    month: DS.attr('date'),
    year: DS.attr('date'),
    daysName: DS.attr('array'),
    daysInMonth: DS.attr('array'),
    weeks: DS.attr('number')
});

WebCalendar.Dates.FIXTURES = [
    {   
        id: 1,
        today: new Date(), 
        month: moment().format('MMM'),
        year: moment().format('YYYY'),
        daysName: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"],
        daysInMonth: [ 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 ],
        weeks: new Array(6)
    }
];
```

And two controller or almost :)
cal_controller.js:

```
WebCalendar.CalController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'days'

});
```

days_controller.js

```
WebCalendar.DaysController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    getMonthDays: function(){
        var monthNumber = this.get("monthNumber");
        var daysInMonth = this.get("daysInMonth");
        var totDayInMonth = daysInMonth[monthNumber];

        var days = [];
        for( i = 1; i < totDayInMonth; i++){
            days.push(i);
        }
        return days;

    }.property('monthNumber')
});
```

and one template, cal.hbs:

```
<table>
        {{#each date in controller}}
            <tr id="year">
                <td>{{date.year}}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id="prev-month"> Prev </td>
                <td id="month">{{date.month}}</td>
                <td id="next-month"> Next </td>
            </tr>

            <tr id="days-of-week">
                {{#each date.daysName}}
                    <td>{{this}}</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>

        {{/each}}

    <tbody>



    {{#each date in controller}} 
        {{#each date.weeks}}
            <tr class="days">{{this}}
                {{#each days itemController="days"}}
                    <td>{{days.getMonthDays}} Days</td>
                {{/each}}
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    {{/each}}

    </tbody>    
</table>
```

So i need to loop throught my weeks model (6) and then loop again thought my days and print them

my idea was to loop in the template before doing date in controller and then days in controller but of[course I need to speficy isn't the default cal controller instead is the days controller that's why I did days in webCal.DaysController
but It complain isn't an Array...

Error:

```
Assertion failed: The value that #each loops over must be an Array. 
You passed WebCalendar.DaysController
```

Why it does that?
And why if i say just days in controller doens't complain that isn't an array controller??

Comment: does the error message say which #each loop is the offending loop? I think the problem is that you're defining itemController within the controller and not "inline" on the specific loop that should be using the days controller. Try {{#each days itemController="days"}}

Comment: no it doesn't say which loop is but I guess the days one since it complain about WebCalendar.DaysController. Anyway I try what you suggest and now it doesn't complain anymore but it not even display whatever I put inside the #each days

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the data structure that you have, for what you are trying to do in the template, weeks would need to be an object containing an array of days.

```
{{#each date in controller}} 
  {{#each date.weeks}}
    <td>{{this}}
      {{#each days itemController='days'}}
          <td>{{days.getMonthDays}} Days</td>
      {{/each}}
    </td>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

*Update*:

A better structure to loop could be created in `DateController`:

```
WebCalendar.DateController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  formattedWeeks: function() {
    var i;
    var monthNumber = this.get('monthNumber');
    var daysInMonth = this.get('daysInMonth');
    var totDayInMonth = daysInMonth[monthNumber];

    var days = [];
    for (i = 1; i < totDayInMonth; i++) {
      days.push(i);
    }

    var weeks = [];
    var fullWeeks = Math.floor(days.length / 7);

    for (i = 0; i < fullWeeks; i++) {
      weeks.push(days.splice(0, 7));
    }

    weeks.push(days);

    return days;
  }.property('monthNumber', 'daysInMonth')
});
```

This will give you an array of arrays, which have the correct numbering, ie:

```
[
   [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
   [8,9,10,11,12,13,14],
   [15,16,17,18,19,20,21],
   [22,23,24,25,26,27,28],
   [29,30]
]
```

And then in your template:

```
{{#each date itemController='date'}} 
  {{#each date.formattedWeeks}}
    <tr>
      {{#each this}}
          <td>{{this}}</td>
      {{/each}}
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

PD: *untested*

Comment: Actually i'm not sure about my data structure as well. Now I updated my template with your solution (it works) and better table structure and doesn't work anymore. Error: Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null. Anyway my idea was to create a week array of 6 spots and loop it in order to create 6 rows, then inside loop till 7(this part isn't there yet) and then insert the days Array with all the days in a month. If you have better structure i very happy to know it, seems you know quite good Emberjs :)

Comment: I updated the answer, may not be what you need exactly but should give you an idea @GiorgiaSambrotta

Comment: ah! That's make totally sense. Is more general way to think it. I like! So doing this, i don't even need to create daysController.ObjectController as itemController of CalController. My CalController become DateController. I will test it and let you know :)